# Root View Controller I can't assign it to class

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this view Controller but't I can't assign to any class [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Dzt.jpg)

Comment: Do you have **any** class that inherits from `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

What class are you trying to assign? Make sure that it inherits from UITableViewController, otherwise it won't be able to assign it. It must be 
something like this:

```
class YourClass: UITableViewController {
//Class implementation
}
```